# Forcing Clang to use GCC C++ runtime libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, cross-compiling, msys2

I'd like to use Clang as a cross-compiler (which it inherently is, according to https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).
The quirk of my setup is that I run it on Windows (MSYS2 installation) to build the code for Linux AArch64 board. It fails on the link stage:

```
ld.lld: error: cannot open C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/17/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-aarch64.a: No such file or directory
[cmake]     ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lunwind
```

The package for Clang in MSYS2 doesn't provide that file. But if I understand correctly, it's a part of C++ runtime libraries, which I could try to replace with GCC C++ runtime libraries. I think I should have these because I have GCC installed on that board and I have downloaded the sysroot from there to my development machine.

How can I change the C++ runtime libs used by Clang during build?

Comment: Do you have an aarch64 version of gcc's runtime libraries?

Comment: @StephenNewell I believe I do, in the downloaded sysroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `-rtlib=libgcc -unwindlib=libgcc`.

And if you wanted to do the opposite, that would be `-rtlib=compiler-rt -unwindlib=libunwind` (those seem to be your defaults).

You might also want `-stdlib=libstdc++` (instead of `-stdlib=libc++`), and I'm assuming you already added `--target=...` and `--sysroot=...`.

Comment: That did the trick, I had to add `--rtlib=libgcc --unwindlib=libgcc` to my args. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandrZarubkin For some reason I didn't think you need `-unwindlib=libgcc`, fixed.

Comment: I get `[build] clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--unwindlib=libgcc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]` messages though. But the build process succeeds. But if I remove `--unwindlib=libgcc`, I get the error that `[cmake]     clang++: error: --rtlib=libgcc requires --unwindlib=libgcc`.